# Title in Editform.aspx in sharepoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form

I open a `newform.aspx`,to add new item.  At the very top I would see the `name of the list view-new form` in my case, `Clients-New Form`. But when I open a item to edit, it shows the `name of the list view - empty`.  The title called edit form is missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the form, SharePoint actually displays "List Name - {Item of the Title}" and NOT "List Name - Edit Form". I think this makes sense.

I think your title field on the item is blank so you do not see it after list name.

Comment: we are not using the title field so it has been hidden,not required field and blank.